# Is it possible to send a float Array over I2c

Tags: arduino-uno, i2c

I have tried it several times myself but i never could send or receive it properly. I am asking myself if it is possible and if so could someone explain how?

Cheers.

Comment: It is possible. You gave to send both bytes of the float and put them back together correctly after it. Please include your code into the question, so that we can help you

Answer (score 1):

Below is a simple rewrite of the Master Writer/Slave Receiver Wire Tutorial, https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/MasterWriter, for a vector of floating-point numbers.

**Master Writer Sketch**

```
#include <Wire.h>

const int DEVICE = 8;

void setup() {
  Wire.begin();
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  const int VEC_MAX = 6;
  float vec[VEC_MAX];
  uint8_t* vp = (uint8_t*) vec;

  Wire.requestFrom(DEVICE, sizeof(vec));
  while (Wire.available()) {
    *vp++ = Wire.read();
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < VEC_MAX; i++) {
    Serial.println(vec[i]);
  }

  delay(500);
}
```

**Slave Receiver Sketch**

```
#include <Wire.h>

const int DEVICE = 8;
const int VEC_MAX = 6;
float vec[VEC_MAX] = { ... };

void setup() {
  Wire.begin(DEVICE);
  Wire.onRequest(requestEvent);
}

void loop() {
  delay(100);
}

void requestEvent() {
  Wire.write((uint8_t*) vec, sizeof(vec));
}
```

> Is it possible to send a float Array over I2c

So I would answer - Yes.